# Modulus in Calculus?

Tags: derivatives, calculus

Does Modulus function has any effect during differentiation and integration of a quantity?

For example:

Let two velocities be:

$$ v_1= (t-2) m/s $$
and
$$ v_2=|t-2|m/s $$

If we differentiate them to get the acceleration of the particle? What impact will it have on the acceleration vector ?

Also if we integrate to get position of the vector? What will be its effect?

Or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Is there a difference between differentiating 5x and -5x?

Comment: Modulus of a vector is only too important. da/dt and d|a|/dt can give absolutely different results for a vector a.

Comment: @Lelouch. For concreteness, consider the velocity $\vec{v}$ in uniform circular motion. The speed is constant but the direction is always changing, which means $d\vec{v}/dt \neq 0$ but $d|\vec{v}|/dt = 0$.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL:  I recommend just trying to differentiate or integrate (say, from $-4 to 0$ those functions and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it has an impact.

For $t<2$, $|t-2|=2-t$, which obviously has a different derivative and antiderivative than $t-2$.